# Is it possible to customize IdentityUserRole table in asp.net identity server 4?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I need to remove existing Composite primary key(UserId and RoleId) in IdentityUserRole table and  add new column 'Id' and also want set that Id column as primary key in asp.net identity server 4?

Comment: What is your target framework? asp.net or asp.net core?

Comment: Oh it's possible but wouldn't suggest doing it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity